# Автоматическое изменение вьюхи Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

есть view

```
create or replace view temp as select * from table;
```

если посмотреть код вьюхи после создания, то увидим вместо `*` явное перечисление наименований атрибутов таблицы.

Таким образом, если в таблицу добавить новый атрибут - во вьюхе его не будет.
Если удалить атрибут - во вьюхе будет ошибка.
Есть решение? Может инструкция, которая рефрешит вьюху?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таких инструкций нет, и вряд ли они имели бы много смысла, если бы были.

Есть "полуавтоматическое" решение. Во-первых, в системных вьюхах `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`/`DBA_DEPENDENCIES`/`USER_DEPENDENCIES` вы можете посмотреть, какие объекты зависят от вашей таблицы, а потом решить, что с ними делать. Например, к изменяемой таблице обращаются 10 вью, а добавляемое поле нужно будет только в трех. Придется слишком сложный синтаксис городить ради поддержки такой фичи.

Во-вторых, в случае удаления поля также можете проверить статусы объектов в системном вью `ALL_OBJECTS` (и его братьях `DBA_OBJECTS` и `USER_OBJECTS`). Если в поле `STATUS` объекта будет стоять `INVALID`, значит, удаление столбца что-то поломало. Учтите, что от таблиц не только вью могут зависеть, но и почти все другие объекты.